# How can a field of number data type be formatted to allow its inputted value to retain a nonzero number one digit to the right of a decimal point?

Tags: number-formatting, ms-access-2013, primary-key-design

I have tried setting up a primary key with either General Number or Fixed format, and I set the decimal point to 1 digit... as soon as I finish typing into the table an amount (e.g. 101.1), as soon as I click the pointer on another field, the value changes instead to 101.0!  I want the decimal value to retain after entry and not become 101.0 instead of the desired 101.1.

Comment: Okay.  After hours of fighting with this issue, I discovered that one cannot edit an existing datasheet by adding another field to it and expecting digits to the right side of the decimal to remain.  For some reason, under this arrangement, any field with a numeric data type will accept only the whole number that is inputted and will reject the digits to the right of the decimal. Also, in my case, the relationships to the table where this was occurring were all removed, so this was not part of the problem.

Comment: the only way to fix is to set up a new table and allow for more than one digits to the right of the decimal.  Under this "blank slate" situation, the digits to the right of the decimal point will be accepted as a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Open table in design mode and for primary key with Number data type select Field Size as Double instead of default Long Integer, which cannot store floating point values